# Why next-auth google provider work in development but always returns "Try signing in with a different account" in production?

Tags: oauth, google-oauth, production-environment, next-auth, next.js13

OAuth login with google fails and always returns "Try signing in with a different account", however it works pretty fine in development.

- I have created credentials for my OAuth service
- Added the development and production domains:

  - http://localhost:3000
  - https://affiliatenetwork.help
- Authorized redirect URIs

  - http://localhost:3000/api/auth/callback/google
  - https://affiliatenetwork.help/api/auth/callback/google
- Set the app to production mode

  - [OAuth consent screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w5NpQ.png)
  - [Scopes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xldcN.png)

but login only works in a development environment

##### When I used debug mode "checks.state argument is missing" Error has been raised

[next-auth][error][OAUTH_CALLBACK_ERROR]
https://next-auth.js.org/errors#oauth_callback_error checks.state argument is missing {
error: TypeError: checks.state argument is missing
at Client.callback (/home/emadu/arab-deals/node_modules/openid-client/lib/client.js:387:13)
at oAuthCallback (/home/emadu/arab-deals/node_modules/next-auth/core/lib/oauth/callback.js:127:29)
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
at async Object.callback (/home/emadu/arab-deals/node_modules/next-auth/core/routes/callback.js:52:11)
at async AuthHandlerInternal (/home/emadu/arab-deals/node_modules/next-auth/core/index.js:167:28)
at async AuthHandler (/home/emadu/arab-deals/node_modules/next-auth/core/index.js:309:28)
at async NextAuthHandler (/home/emadu/arab-deals/node_modules/next-auth/next/index.js:24:20)
at async /home/emadu/arab-deals/node_modules/next-auth/next/index.js:50:32
at async Object.apiResolver (/home/emadu/arab-deals/node_modules/next/dist/server/api-utils/node.js:363:9)
at async DevServer.runApi (/home/emadu/arab-deals/node_modules/next/dist/server/next-server.js:474:9) {
name: 'OAuthCallbackError',
code: undefined
},
providerId: 'google',
message: 'checks.state argument is missing'
}